# Como accedo a una foto dentro del photo album

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Quisiera saber como accedo a una foto guardada dentro del photo album del dispositivo. He utilizado `UIImagePickerController` pero no necesito que se abra la galería de fotos y seleccionar la foto. Quisiera que por medio del código le mande el nombre de la imagen que necesito y la retorne. ¿Existe alguna función para lograr esto?

Comment: pero no para seleccionarlas lo que quiero hacer es con el nombre del archivo de la foto quiero poder acceder a ella, gracias.

Comment: Ya viste `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: si pero eso permite es seleccionarla abriendo el photo album, no necesito que se abra la galeria de fotos y seleccionar la foto, por medio del codigo le mando el nombre de la imagen y la necesito que me la retorne pero no se como lo hago con que funcion o q?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias probar usar Photo Framework, te dejo el código en objective-c, espero alguien pueda pasarlo a swift

```
-(void)getAllPhotosFromCamera
{
    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    requestOptions.synchronous = true;
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)result.count);

    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[result count]];

    // assets contiene los objetos PHAsset.

    __block UIImage *ima;
    for (PHAsset *asset in result) {
        // Do something with the asset

        [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
            targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                    options:requestOptions
        resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
            ima = image;

            [images addObject:ima];
        }];


    }

    imageArray = [images copy];   
}
```